# display an HTML page(containg audio player) in felx AIR

Tags: php, html, apache-flex, air

```
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{$field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    'echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["area"] . "</td>";
    echo '<td> .  <embed height="18" width="100" src="'.$row["voicename"].'"> . <td>';
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body></html>
```

this code is working fine.it will display a table in browser with tow field.the second field will display a quick time plugin which will play the mp3 file(name is voicename and it's stored in the same folder that of this html file).But I need to display this HTML page on flex AIR. table is displaying.but player is not displaying since quick time plugin is not there with flex air interface.is there any way to display player there?

Comment: Try to check syntax. It have some issues.

Comment: this code is working fine...it will display a table in browser with tow field.the second field will display a quick time plugin which will play the mp3 file(name is voicename and it's stored in the same folder that of this html file).But I need to display this HTML page on flex AIR. table is displaying.but player is not displaying since quick time plugin is not there with flex air interface.is there any way i have to display player there?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML facilities of Adobe AIR do not support the Quicktime plugin; they only support the Flash Player plugin.  So I do not believe you will be able to do what you want.

Comment: Then How can i play a audio file in server using flash player in a flex app?

Comment: In a Flex / Flash app you can use the sound class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html to play audio.  In theory, you could embed a Flash MP3 player in your HTML page and that should work.